# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined in Dygraphs?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

When zooming on the Y-axis on Android in Chrome sometimes website scroll to the top. When attaching a debugger there is an error in 520 line of the code:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined dygraphs

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it find the code in dygraph.js:

```
if (touches.length == 1) {
    xScale = 1.0;
    yScale = 1.0;
```

And change it to:

```
if (touches.length == 1 || initialTouches.length == 1) {
    xScale = 1.0;
    yScale = 1.0;
```